# choose random value only once

Tags: random, background-image

My page loads a random background image every time it loads:

```
<?php
    $input = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8);
    $num = array_rand($input, 1);
    $bg = "img/bg" . $num . ".jpg";
?>
```

But I want it to do that only once. I want the image to remain the same after a visitor submits a form, for example, thereby reloading the page.

I've tried if($bg=NULL) etc, but to no avail - I guess $bg becomes null again every time the page reloads.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Session variable](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php) or [cookies](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_cookies.asp) if is not set, you choose a background, if is set, you do nothing

Answer (score 0):

Got it (thanks to Ricardo):

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if (!isset($_SESSION['num'])) {
        $input = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8);
        $_SESSION['num'] = array_rand($input, 1);
    }

    $bg = "img/bg" . $_SESSION['num'] . ".jpg";
?>
```