# Random image only to be applied once

Tags: javascript

I want my website to show a random background image (which I've set up with javascript) but I don't want it to change again while the user is on the site.  At the moment it changes every time you click a link, but I'd rather it only change when you hit the Home button.

I think this other question is similar, but as I haven't used php much before, I was wondering if there was a javascript alternative? (or just something silly i missing here?)
[choose random value only once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14429795/choose-random-value-only-once)

Thanks

Comment: Use a [session](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php) variable.

Comment: use a php session variable and echo it on javascript if you like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Javascript solution (fully client side):

Use `sessionStorage`

```
fileurls=["a.jpg","b,jpg"]// list of file URLS
function getFileURL(){
 if(sessionStorage.fileurl)
  return sessionStorage.fileurl;
 }else{
  sessionStorage.fileurl=fileurls[Math.floor(Math.rand()*fileurls.length)]
  return sessionStorage.fileurl;
 }
}
```

Now, just set the `src` of the image to whatever is set by the function:

```
document.body.style.background="url('"+getFileURL()+"')";
```

Basically, this puts a random file URL in browser storage for a session, and uses it whenever required.

---

### PHP solution (fully server side):

```
$fileurls = array('a.jpg','b,jpg');
if(!isset($_SESSION['fileurl'])) {
    $_SESSION['fileurl'] = $fileurls[rand(0, count($fileurls) - 1)];
}
```

And, wherever the `<body>` tag is, do this:

```
 <body background="<?echo$_SESSION ['fileurl'];  ?>">
```

Comment: Thanks very much, the javascript solution worked perfectly! To anyone else that might be looking at this for help, I used an `onlick` on my home page link to run a function with `delete sessionStorage.fileurl;` in it to reset the session variable and therefore change the background when you click on the home page only.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [cookies](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp) or even `window.localStorage` to store informations in Javascript through navigation (and then use the same logic as in your link).

Answer (score -1):

Use JavaScript to set an onClickListener for the Home button which will change the background when clicked.